# How to scale JavaFX DatePicker and transform to a calendar?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to transform the `DatePickerContent` to a calendar but I'm having trouble setting the correct size. While the calendar resizes horizontally it doesn't vertically. Basically I'd like it to have the same size as the as the parent node. Also the `DateCell`s don't have all the same size. They depend on their content.

How can I achieve that? Here is some of my code:

```
DatePickerSkin pickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker());
DatePickerContent calendar = (DatePickerContent) pickerSkin.getPopupContent();
// ...
StackPane pane = new StackPane();
pane.getChildren().add(calendar);
// ...
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image: Date Picker]

Comment: It's probably going to be easier to roll your own calendar implementation, using e.g. a `GridPane`, than to repurpose the skin for the date picker for this.

Comment: I started a calendar [here](https://github.com/sedj601/CalendarFx) if you want to check it out.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Thanks but I just rolled my own. Turned out to be not that hard.